# Is it OK to ask a question about Chinese etiquette

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently read this question: [Japanese etiquette: Most common (and offensive) mistakes?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/japanese-etiquette-most-common-and-offensive-mistakes)

The first comment questioned the applicability of this question to SE. I'd be interested in answers to a similar question about China. Will this be a problem?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/chinese-etiquette-most-common-mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say go ahead and ask. If we're so far undecided whether these questions are on-topic then getting a bunch of them will help force us to decide. And if we decide they are on-topic you will probably get the answer you are looking for.